# How to edit .jar file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, jar, android-studio, libs

How can I edit code in a .class file in a .jar file using Android Studio? I have already tried to edit it of course. The class I am trying to edit is a read only for some reason.

Comment: I'm not a java expert but jar file is a package of compiled code. You can't edit jar file. You mast find source of the class or decompile jar file end recreate it.

Comment: This doesn't relate... Read the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Jar` files are compressed archives (zipped files) of `.class` files( and few other resources). `.class` files are compiled `.java` files. You can not edit a compiled file in normal situation unless you decompile to get source code, edit the code and recompile again.

Decompiling is a tedious process, thus getting a source code is the best option here.

**Note:** You can rename the `.jar` file to a `.zip` file and can open it using any compression tool such as `winrar` or `winzip` to see the content.