# Android targetSdk backward compatibility

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, target-sdk

Haven't found an answer to this. I'm trying to integrate an external lib into my android project. My `targetSdkVersion` is `27`. The external lib's documentation mentions that it "supports" `targetSdkVersion` `25`. What does this mean? Can I integrate it into my app without changing my `targetSdkVersion` (which I obviously dont want)? Is it backward compatible like that? I havent found any exact info on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the external library supports only till SDK 25. You'll have to copy it to your project and manually update the SDK version in the external library, and hope it works. Till SDK 25 is actually pretty good, so you might not face any problems while compiling. If there are any problems, you'll have to go in and fix it in the code. Another solution is to raise a request to the original author, but there won't be any guarantee on when he'll do it and upload the project.

Comment: So if its a JAR that means there is no way it will build? Or can there be only runtime problems?

Comment: Hmm, I haven't done edits on a jar file, but please do check this link out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478227/how-to-edit-jar-file-in-android-studio
If the renaming thing works, and you're able to get all the code, then just import it into your project. Otherwise, I guess there isn't a way.

Comment: If you feel your question has been answered, please mark this answer as accepted and close this one. If you have some other questions, please open that as a new question :)

Comment: Sure, I will have to wait some it seems for that but I will

Comment: Oh the 30 min thing... forgot about that! Thanks! :D